# In flutter how can I go back to previous URL when the back button is pressed?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin

I am completely new to flutter, I am using web view widget , but whenever I am pressing back it exits the app. How can I go back to previous page while the back button is pressed?

Here is my code snippet

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
WebViewController controllerGlobal;

Future<bool> _exitApp(BuildContext context) async {
  if (await controllerGlobal.canGoBack()) {
    print("onwill goback");
    controllerGlobal.goBack();
    return Future.value(true);
  } else {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(content: Text("No back history item")),
    );
    return Future.value(false);
  }
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'TRAVMAKS',
      home: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () => _exitApp(context),
        child:Scaffold(
              body: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 52.0),
                    child: Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                            child: WebView(
                                        initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
                                        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                        )
              )
        )
    )
    )
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `true` after navigating back in your `WebView`. If you return `true` in `onWillPop`, Flutter pops the route and if it's your root route, the app will exit. You may want to return false there too.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope/onWillPop.html